# Create bootable RedHat iso from folder

Tags: boot, virtualbox, iso-image, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'd like to install RedHat 6.4 (32bits) on a VM. The problem is that I don't have the iso file. Instead, I have access to a folder (standard RedHat folder with subfolders like `images`, `isolinux`, etc.)

I can't manage to recreate a bootable iso file from this folder. Each time I tried, VirtualBox say `FATAL: no bootable medium found! System halted`. I assume that my ISO file is not built correctly (not bootable?).

I think virtualBox is configured correctly (the iso file is set for the virtual CD/DVD).

How I tried to create the ISO file:

- using programs: isoCreator, powerIso
- using command: `mkisofs -o genertatedIso.iso /MyRep`

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example:

```
mkisofs -r -R -J -T -v -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -V 'my-rhel6.4' -p 'RHEL6.4' -A 'RHEL6.4' -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -o /var/tmp/my-rhel6.4.iso /path-of-your-distro
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify a boot image and a boot catalog for `mkisofs` to make the disk bootable. These files are often called `isolinux.bin` and `boot.cat` respectively, and you should specify them to `mkisofs` via the `-b` and `-c` flags:

```
mkisofs -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot -o genertatedIso.iso /MyRep
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Looks like I'm able to boot on something, but the Image appeared to be damaged `ISOLINUX 4.02 2010-07-21 ETCDisolinux: Image checksum error, sorry... Boot failed`