# Copying contents of an ISO to new folder and recreating it makes the ISO become not bootable?

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, iso-image

I'm working on upgrading a system from RHEL6 to RHEL7 and in the meantime I need to do a few tests before I actually upgrade. My question is: I have a working RHEL7 stock ISO file downloaded from Red Hat's website, and I attempted to copy the contents of the ISO to a folder on my computer, and then turn that folder into a new ISO (using various ISO-creating utilities), just to make sure I could do that. However, the problem is, despite me making no changes before "recompiling it", when I try to use this recreated ISO in VirtualBox, I get a fatal error: no bootable medium found error. What could be causing this?

Comment: Is the file structure the same in your new ISO? For example, the new ISO might have the OS stuff in *yourfolder*->OS inside of the ISO.

Comment: If the files structure is the same then you need to make sure you are creating a bootable ISO. http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-add-files-to-bootable-iso-in-windows/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create bootable RedHat iso from folder](http://superuser.com/questions/992000/create-bootable-redhat-iso-from-folder)

Comment: To be _bootable_ a disk has to have a [valid boot sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector). When you copy the contents, (...), and you make a new disk without the correct boot sector you have a normal disk full with the data. Check [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux/7/anaconda-customization-guide/2-working-with-iso-images) about how to do a bootable iso image. (Look for `-b` option of `genisoimage`). [Minimal guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/Making_Minimal_Boot_Media.html).

Comment: ps> Welcome on SuperUser.

Comment: have you been sure to copy hidden files as well?

Comment: If you copied the ISO as a file and kept it that way, you shouldn't need to re-create anything.  Just burn it to media or mount it to use it.  If it is a normal ISO (not a hybrid), that will be bootable only if burned to optical media.  To boot it from anything else, you need to add a boot record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps for copying and doing a fixup on an iso image:

1. Make a temporary directory for the contents of your iso:

   ```
   # mkdir /var/tmp/isodir
   ```
2. Make a temporary mount dir for the iso:

   ```
   # mkdir /id
   ```
3. Mount the iso:

   ```
   # mount -oro,loop /path/to/file.iso /id
   ```
4. Copy the contents to the new path:

   ```
   # cd /id
   # cp -av . /var/tmp/isodir
   ```
5. Go over into /var/tmp/isodir and do whatever mods you need.
6. Recreate your .iso:

   ```
   # cd /var/tmp/isodir
   # mkisofs -o /path/to/new/file.iso -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T isolinux/
   ```
7. Cleanup:

   ```
   # umount /id
   # rmdir /id
   ```

Explanation: The mkisofs command above uses the -b flag to specify the boot image (isolinux.bin). (The rest of the flags can be found in the man page for mkisofs.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've gotten the rebuilt ISO to boot, although it's getting stuck in the install process.

Answer (score 1):

To be *bootable* a disk has to have a [valid boot sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector). When you copy the contents, (...), and you make a new disk without the correct boot sector you have a normal disk full with the data. Check [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux/7/anaconda-customization-guide/2-working-with-iso-images) about how to do a bootable iso image. (Look for `-b` option of `genisoimage`).

Look here for a [Minimal guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/Making_Minimal_Boot_Media.html).